# How to track add bot in discord? python discord.py api

Tags: python, api, discord.py

I'm sorry for this perhaps the obvious question, but unfortunately in the documentation to the library discord.py I could not find information about the event of adding a bot to the server, is there such an event in this library, and if not, then maybe there is an api method in discord itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an [`on_server_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_server_join) event.  If you wanted to print the name of the server to the terminal when you join, for example, you could do

```
@client.event
async def on_server_join(server):
    print(server.name)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I saw that these properties are there, but thought about something else(

Answer (score 0):

If you want the bot to connect to the discord server you have to create it first: `client = discord.Client()`

And then you have to start him:

```
client.run(YOUR_USER_TOKEN)
```